# Loop through ng-options in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to push an array of values inside select box using ng-options in Angularjs.

**Handlebars:**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by 
    item.id" ng-model="selected">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {

$scope.arealistArray=[];
$scope.items=[]; 

for(j=1;j<3;j++){
    $scope.arealistArray.push([{id: 'id'+j,label: 'aLabel'+j,subItem: { 
    name: 'aSubItem'+j }}]);
} 

$scope.items = $scope.arealistArray;
```

My options are appending in the select box, but the **value** and **label** are undefined for appended options. Is there any restriction using push in ng-options? Or any thing I want to change here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing an array in an other array. You shall remove the "[]".

```
$scope.arealistArray.push({
  id: 'id' + j,
  label: 'aLabel' + j,
  subItem: {
    name: 'aSubItem' + j
  }
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8uq5nyo7/1/) based on your code.

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that I've updated my answer. After some research the `track by` expression you have on your code is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.arealistArray.push([{id: 'id'+j,label: 'aLabel'+j,subItem: { 
name: 'aSubItem'+j }}]);
```

if it's like above you need to specify index  or else

```
 ng-options="item as item.label for item in items[0] track by item.id"
```

if its an object remove the [] while doing push.

```
$scope.arealistArray.push({id: 'id'+j,label: 'aLabel'+j,subItem: { 
name: 'aSubItem'+j }});
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope) {

$scope.arealistArray=[];
$scope.items=[]; 

for(j=1;j<3;j++){
    $scope.arealistArray.push({id: 'id'+j,label: 'aLabel'+j,subItem: { 
    name: 'aSubItem'+j }});
} 

$scope.items = $scope.arealistArray;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller" class="col-md-8">
    <select  ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by 
item.id" ng-model="selected">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```